# Get text from dynamically created EditText

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, dynamically-generated

in the program I have 3 fields to enter when I enter data and pressed for starting the button below creates three dynamic input fields, the program calculates the average score of only 3 top fields. I want that when the user changed any data in dynamically created fields it counted the data from these fields, regardless of their number

```
 package com.example.averegemark;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.graphics.Color;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.LinearLayout;
    import android.widget.TableLayout;
    import android.widget.TableRow;
    import android.widget.TableRow.LayoutParams;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

public class Table extends Activity {

    LinearLayout LL;
    EditText et1,et2,et3;
    double coef=0,points=0,sum=0,coefsum=0;
    TextView total;
    Button bNext;
    String name="",mark="",coeff="";
    int i=0;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.table);
        bNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bNext);
        et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et1);
        et2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et2);
        et3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et3);
        total = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTotal);
        total.setText("GPA:");
        LL = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LL);

        bNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                name = et1.getText().toString();
                mark = et2.getText().toString();
                coeff = et3.getText().toString();
                if(mark.length()==0 || coeff.length()==0)
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter mark `and coefficient", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                else
                    NewView(name,mark,coeff);
            }
        });

    }   

    private void NewView(String name, String mark, String coeff) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        EditText info1 = new EditText(this);
        EditText info2 = new EditText(this);
        EditText info3 = new EditText(this);

        info1.setId(i);i++;
        info1.setId(i);i++;
        info1.setId(i);i++;

        info1.setText(""+name);
        info2.setText(""+mark);
        info3.setText(""+coeff);


        TableLayout table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tbl);
        table.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
        row.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        row.addView(info1);
        row.addView(info2);
        row.addView(info3);

        table.addView(row);


        String rez="";
        rez= info2.getText().toString();
        points = Double.parseDouble(rez);
        rez= info3.getText().toString();
        coef = Double.parseDouble(rez);
        sum +=coef*points;
        coefsum+=coef;
        sum/=coefsum;
        total.setText("GPA : "+sum+"\nCoefficient sum. "+coefsum);

        et3.setText("");
        et2.setText("");
        et1.setText("");
        et1.requestFocus();
    }
}
```

so when I will change any data in row , i want to recalculate this, but here it use only top EditText not dynamically created :

```
            String rez="";
        rez= info2.getText().toString();
        points = Double.parseDouble(rez);
        rez= info3.getText().toString();
        coef = Double.parseDouble(rez);
        sum +=coef*points;
        coefsum+=coef;
        sum/=coefsum;
        total.setText("GPA : "+sum+"\nCoefficient sum. "+coefsum);
```

Comment: I read this like 5 times now and I don't get it. Maybe the problem is me, but maybe it helps if you re-phrased your question.

Comment: OKEY, you see , there is 3 EditText created in layout , each time when you enter data and press button next , below them creates 3 new EditText with the same data . Program calculate GPA  = coefficient * mark \ coefficient sum;

I want program to recalculate GPA each time when user  change some data in dynamically created EditText .

Sorry , for me is very difficult to formulate questions correctly.

Comment: private void GetCount(){
  
  TableLayout table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tbl);
  
  ArrayList<EditText> metl = new ArrayList<EditText>();
  
  try{
  for( int i = 0; i < table.getChildCount(); i++ )
    if( table.getChildAt( i ) instanceof EditText )
      metl.add( (EditText) table.getChildAt( i ) );

  
  }catch(Exception e){
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error:  "+e.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }
 }

Answer (score 0):

When you press the button, you get the information from the original edittexts. You have to find the last row in the table and get the edittexts from there.

Answer (score 0):

```
CharSequence data = ((TextView) v).getText();
String result = data.toString();
```